# Set type of http request

Tags: java, android, http

How to set type of http request, using org.apache.* library? For example, if I need **POST** request:

```
HttpPost hp=new HttpPost("http://server.com");
```

or **GET**

```
HttpGet hg=new HttpGet("http://server.com");
```

It works fine. But in my project I want to use only one function for all types of requests, because I need also **PUT** and **DELETE** requests.

So, how can I set type of request in **DefaultHttpClient** or (if it's impossible) how can I create **PUT** and **DELETE** requests?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
HttpMethod httpMethod = new HttpPost("http://server.com");
```

In your common function you can use `httpMethod.getName();` which will return the type of HTTP call you are doing.

Syntax for PUT/DELETE method are:

```
  HttpMethod httpMethod = new PutMethod("http://server.com");
  HttpMethod httpMethod = new DeleteMethod("http://server.com");
```

Answer (score 2):

There are similar functions available for PUT and DELETE requests:

```
HttpPut hg = new HttpPut("http://server.com");
HttpDelete hg = new HttpDelete("http://server.com");
```

See http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpPut.html

If you want only one function you can create a wrapper function like this:

```
public HttpRequestBase httpRequest(String uri, String method) {
   switch(method) {
     case "PUT":
       return new HttpPut(uri);
     case "DELETE":
       return new HttpDelete(uri);
     case "POST":
       return new HttpPost(uri);
     case "GET":
       return new HttpGet(uri);
     default:
       return null;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[List of all the methods.](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/methods.html)

[Put](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/methods/put.html):

```
PutMethod put = new PutMethod("http://jakarta.apache.org");
```

[Delete](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/methods/delete.html)

```
DeleteMethod delete = new DeleteMethod("http://jakarata.apache.org");
```

Comment: Thanks. But there is no way to solve my problem without creating a object for each type of request? With these methods I will get 4 different implementations.